# Why vuejs3 nested v-for, child v-for not resetting index to 0?

Tags: vuejs3, v-for

I have this template:

```
const props = defineProps(["products"]);

<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-4" v-for="(product,prodindex) in props.products" :key="prodindex">
    <div class="carousel-item" :class={'active': imgindex===0} v-for="(image,imgindex) in product.images" :key="imgindex" :class="{ 'active': imgindex === 0 }" >
        <img :d="imgindex" :src="apiEndpoint+image.previewURL" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

I wonder why `imgindex` is not resettig its value to 0 even if it is from different product.

Example:

1. `product.name` = Burger has 2 images, `imgindex` should be 0,1.
2. `product.name` = Pizza has 5 images, `imgindex` should be 0,1,2,3,4.

But what happen is, `imgindex` is not resetting to 0, it continues to something like this: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Any Idea? Thank you :)

Comment: Is `:d="imgindex"` supposed to be `:id`?  There's two class bindings on the `carousel-item`, the first would produce errors for not being surrounded in quotes, although having more than one would also be an error.  I assume you've introduced typos into the code when pasting it somehow which makes it harder to know what's a typo vs. what's actually wrong.  Regardless, assuming the obvious errors are typos, the basic idea of the code is sound and doesn't reproduce your error. See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-butterfly-zrowcv?file=/src/App.vue)